# VBScript for autologin but failed

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am trying to write a VBscript for auto login for a particular url,but the problem is that i am not able to automatically enter the password .

The unique property for password(I used Object Spy) is WebEdit:WebEdit(Property:Value). Webedit is not getting identified by Object Repository even if i am adding to it.

So my question how do i automate the password input , if the attributes have no "ID","Name",and only webedit as unique property.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no ID or name property, look for someother unique property like CSS class name etc (css class names need not be unique always. It could be in some cases)

As you are trying to access password field, you can use the 'type' property.

```
type=text       ==> It is normal textboxes

type=password   ==> It is a password field
```

Ordinal identifiers can be used as well.

```
index=0  It identifies the first textbox 

index=1  It identifies the second textbox etc..
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i've tried using index, it is unique but still it doesn't work.The problem is when i try the above property the text gets entered into the password textbox( as hidden),but when i click on log-in ,the textbox content is vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the Unique Property  for the password field, if not getting identifying give all the properties
even though it is not getting identified then go for index , by changing the index value like 0,1.... etc at some value the object will get identified

Thanks